# Heroku node js no web process running

Tags: node.js, heroku, jemalloc

Locally there is no problem.

The app is deployed to heroku but I get an error screen. In the logs I get:

heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=catan-manager-api.herokuapp.com request_id=c68d7131-7572-4fe6-ae9d-13836519e25c fwd="79.176.191.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=catan-manager-api.herokuapp.com request_id=7f9a1aa9-c079-456c-9f9a-2522bfdc87f7 fwd="79.176.191.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

For some reason it detects is as jemalloc app, not sure if this is relevant, from the deployment:
[image]

I added jemalloc because I had an error using the sharp library, took solution from [here](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#heroku)

1. How come it detects it as jemalloc app? I thought jemalloc is just a library for better memory allocation.
2. How can I fix this, assuming this is the problem?
3. I'm also using @babel, and I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/@kimtnguyen/how-to-deploy-es6-node-js-express-back-end-to-heroku-7e6743e8d2ff)
4. I don't have a Procfile, for node js heroku [knows to use start in package json](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/370)
5. When I try to scale I get "Couldn't find that process type (web)" (obviously...)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following command?

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```

for more information https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing jemalloc and seems to work so far, maybe this will help someone.